# How to use newer versions of HBase on Amazon Elastic MapReduce?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hbase, emr, amazon-emr

Amazon's Elastic MapReduce tool seems to only have support for HBase v0.92.x and v0.94.x.

The [documentation for the EMR AMIs and HBase](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-hbase-versions.html) is seemingly out-of-date and there is no information about HBase on the newest release label emr-4.0.0.

Using this [example from an AWS engineer](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx3CFT0COINZ4N8/Getting-HBase-Running-on-Amazon-EMR-and-Connecting-it-to-Amazon-Kinesis), I was able to concoct a way to install another version of HBase on the nodes, but it was ultimately unsuccessful.

After much trial and error with the Java SDK to provision EMR with better versions, I ask:

Is it possible to configure EMR to use more recent versions of HBase (e.g. 0.98.x and newer?)

Answer (score 3):

After several days of trial, error and support tickets to AWS, I was able to implement HBase 0.98 on Amazon's ElasticMapReduce service. Here's how to do it using the Java SDK, some bash and ruby-based bootstrap actions.

Credit for these bash and ruby scripts goes to Amazon support. They are in-development scripts and not officially supported. It's a hack.

**Supported Version:** HBase 0.98.2 for Hadoop 2

I also created mirrors in Google Drive for the supporting files incase Amazon pulls them down from S3.

**Java SDK example**

```
RunJobFlowRequest jobFlowRequest = new RunJobFlowRequest()
    .withSteps(new ArrayList<StepConfig>())
    .withName("HBase 0.98 Test")
    .withAmiVersion("3.1.0")
    .withInstances(instancesConfig)
    .withLogUri(String.format("s3://bucket/path/to/logs")
    .withVisibleToAllUsers(true)
    .withBootstrapActions(new BootstrapActionConfig()
        .withName("Download HBase")
        .withScriptBootstrapAction(new ScriptBootstrapActionConfig()
                .withPath("s3://bucket/path/to/wget/ssh/script.sh"))
    )
    .withBootstrapActions(new BootstrapActionConfig()
        .withName("Install HBase")
        .withScriptBootstrapAction(new ScriptBootstrapActionConfig()
                .withPath("s3://bucket/path/to/hbase/install/ruby/script"))
    )
    .withServiceRole("EMR_DefaultRole")
    .withJobFlowRole("EMR_EC2_DefaultRole");
```

**"Download HBase" Bootstrap Action (bash script)**

[Original from S3](https://vishg-emr-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/hbase98/wget.sh)

[Mirror from Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxnAULucVci8cncyT2tlcTgtRTQ/view?usp=sharing)

**"Install HBase" Bootstrap Action (ruby script)**

[Original from S3](https://vishg-emr-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/hbase98/setup-hbase)

[Mirror from Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxnAULucVci8ZGFrajVTc0FyTWc/view?usp=sharing)

**HBase Installation Tarball (used in "Download HBase" script)**

[Original from S3](https://vishg-emr-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/hbase98/hbase-0.98.2-hadoop2-bin.tar.gz)

[Mirror from Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxnAULucVci8U1BndzZVUVd0Q2s/view?usp=sharing)

**Make copies of these files**

I highly recommend that you download these files and upload them into your own S3 bucket for use in your bootstrap actions / and scripts. Adjust where necessary.